# Manage object in AWS S3 Glacier stored objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have an s3 bucket `bucket1` containing  some object belonging to S3 storage class and some stored in Glacier class.

I want to move these objects to another bucket `bucket2`. The objects after move to  `bucket2` will still be in the same storage class as they were before.
For example  if `//bucket1/file1` is in Glacier before the move, after move `//bucket2/file1`  will still be in Glacier.
How can I move objects already in Glacier to a different s3 bucket ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in Glacier or Glacier Deep Archive [must be restored before you can operate on them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/restoring-objects.html), so you'll need to restore them in `bucket1` before you can move them to `bucket2`. As part of restore you specify how long you want them to stay in standard storage class before they revert to Glacier.

When you move them, the objects will start out in standard storage class in `bucket2`. You'll need to [create a lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html) rule in `bucket2` to then change the storage class of the moved objects to Glacier.